# Will HttpGet headers override httpClient headers (Apache HttpClient)?

Tags: httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x

I want to set header at the HttpClient, since I want most of my service calls to have the default headers.

```
RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom().setConnectTimeout(ApacheHttpClient.DEFAULT_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT)
            .setSocketTimeout(ApacheHttpClient.DEFAULT_SOCKET_TIMEOUT).build();

    httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setDefaultHeaders(getDefaultHeaderList()).setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig).setRetryHandler(new RetryHandler()).build();
```

However, I would like to replace the default headers, if required. I would be setting it as HttpGet header.

```
int cTimeout = (connTimeout == null) ? DEFAULT_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT : connTimeout;
    int sTimeout = (socketTimeout == null) ? DEFAULT_SOCKET_TIMEOUT : socketTimeout;
    httpGet.setConfig(RequestConfig.custom().setConnectTimeout(cTimeout).setSocketTimeout(sTimeout).build());
```

Would the HttpGet header override the headers set at the HttpClient?

Comment: Try it out with http://httpbin.org/. The /headers endpoint will be most useful - you'll just parse response body as JSON and you'll see what has been sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debugging the request, in `org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(HttpHost, HttpRequest, HttpContext)` I can see that config which holds the timeouts is first obtained from the request and if it not set, the default is used:

```
  RequestConfig config = null;
        if (request instanceof Configurable) {
            config = ((Configurable) request).getConfig();
        }
        if (config == null) {
            final HttpParams params = request.getParams();
            if (params instanceof HttpParamsNames) {
                if (!((HttpParamsNames) params).getNames().isEmpty()) {
                    config = HttpClientParamConfig.getRequestConfig(params);
                }
            } else {
                config = HttpClientParamConfig.getRequestConfig(params);
            }
        }
        if (config != null) {
            localcontext.setRequestConfig(config);
        }
        setupContext(localcontext);
```